# Changing Rational Expressions into a Sum (or Difference) of Rational Expressions in Maple

Tags: maple

Given $\dfrac{x^4+x^3-4x^2-4x}{x^4+x^3-x^2-x}$, is there a way to make it into a sum or difference of rationals such as:

$\dfrac{x^2}{(x-1)(x+1)}-4\dfrac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}?$

I've tried using `factor` and `normal` but with no luck. I think the closest I've gotten to getting the desired result is with `normal(p/factor(q))`, where `p:=x^4+x^3-4x^2-4x` and `q:=x^4+x^3-x^2-x`. However this only gives me `x^2-4/(x+1)(x-1)`. I think that I am on the right track in defining `p` and `q` as the numerator and denominator, respectively. Any help would be appreciated; thanks.

Comment: A preliminary step is to do "long division" to get, in this case, $1$, and a fraction with the highest power in the numerator **less** than the highest power in the denominator...

Comment: `expand( factor( p/q ) )` should do the trick.

Comment: @m_1: Oh wow, that works. Could you explain why? I thought that `expand` and `factor` would cancel each other out, leaving just the original `p/q`? Also, if you put your comment as an answer, I'll put it as best answer. :)

Comment: I absolutely can't explain why that works. :D
Maple works in strange ways and its functions should not be treated as mathematical operators, especially `op`, `simplify` and `expand`. Big parts of Maple's behaviour are actually influenced by the underlying data structures. Try checking the equality of two matrices to get an idea of what I mean.

Comment: Consider `p=x^4-6*x^2-5*x` and `q=x^4+x^3-x^2-x` as another example. Then `expand(factor(p/q))` will produce a sum of three terms each with denominator `(x-1)*(x+1)`. Would you prefer that to the sum of three terms (shorter and with different denominators) produced by instead calling `convert(p/q,parfrac)`? Is it central to your goal, that the denominator be common?

Comment: @acer: I haven't used Maple in a while, so I'm just a bit rusty. I've just been doing some review problems, but for this question I was trying to make sure the denominators were common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `factor` to obtain a factorisation of both numerator and denominator. `expand` called on a rational function expands it into a sum (as opposed to calling `expand` on the numerator or denominator, which indeed would revert the factorisation).

So `expand(factor(p/q))` gets your job done.

Answer (score 3):

As @acer comented you can do that by the following codes:

```
[> p:=x^4+x^3-4x^2-4x: q:=x^4+x^3-x^2-x:
   convert(p/q, parfrac);
```

---

```
                         1-3/(2*(x-1))+3/(2*(x+1))
```